# List lacks delete animation when custom cell is not surrounded by HStack

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a List in SwiftUI which includes custom cells for each item of an array. The cells are basically just `DisclosureGroups` with a button to remove the specific item from the list.
To summarize: I have a list, where each cell has a button to remove itself.

I unexpectedly noticed, that the *removing animation* was not smooth at all.

I added the following modifier to the list `.animation(.default, value: model.tasks)` and surrounded the code for the deletion in the array with `withAnimation {}`

`model.tasks` is the array used to populate the list. It stores an enum which conforms to `Identifiable`, `Equatable` and `CaseIterable`.

Example No.1

```
List {
    ForEach(model.tasks, id: \.self) { task in
        NewCell(task: task)
            .environmentObject(model)
     }
}
```

[image: try no1]

Notice how the cell removes smoothly but the content does not.

Example No.2
This time I surrounded the cell with an HStack

```
List {
    ForEach(model.tasks, id: \.self) { task in
        HStack {
            NewCell(task: task)
                .environmentObject(model)
        }
     }
}
```

[image: try no.2]

This looks exactly how I like it to be.

What is the reason for this strange behavior?

**EDIT:** I actually need to get rid of HStack or VStack, because it will mess up the DisclosureGroup. So I need a good solution for that animation issue.